Overlay two images on a white background
The plt.imshow function does not allow me to overlay two images with a white background. First I masked a region of interest for two different images. Then I tried to overlay the two regions of interest in one image with a white background.
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib

matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))
plt.imshow(img1,vmin=4,vmax=25,cmap='Blues', alpha=0.4)
plt.imshow(img2, cmap='Reds',vmin=4,vmax=25, alpha=0.4)

I used the 'ggplot' style, but it did not work. Below are the output image and expected images.
Output image:

Expected image:

I tried the function plt.plot, but it plots it in a messy way.

What do you mean by "white theme"?

@jared I mean white background similar to the expected/second image

You should share img1 and img2 as well as what you've tried.

It is unclear in which format the "images" are.  If they are numpy arrays of floats, you can replace the values lower than 4 with np.nan to make these pixels fully transparent.

[mre] required. show us the two source images. no screenshots, no plots. you likely just need them blended in the right way. if you interpret this as an image processing task, you might get further: (1) apply colormaps (2) subtractive blend -- disclaimer: I don't know matplotlib well enough. maybe it can do what you want, but I don't know.
